# couldn't access EKS cluster with kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli, kubectl, amazon-eks

i just created a cluster(cluster name = t ) with EKS service and wanted to access the cluster with kubectl .
so after connecting to my aws user and double check the credential and the connection
so i checked to cluster via command and got as output :

```
aws eks list-clusters --
{
    "clusters": [
        "t"
    ]
}
```

and after trying with kubectl :

```
kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.6
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the EKS cluster with root account and tried to acces with another account that's why i couldn't (even that account has AdministratorAccess )

So only the user that created a cluster has access to it